# I can't install google product (google adwords editor ) via Wine

Tags: wine, google

I updated Ubuntu to 15.10 and I can't install Google adwords editor (11.2.1) . When I try to do it via Wine (1.8) I have a info:

```
Unable to connect to the Internet. If you're using firewall, please whitelist GoogleUpdate.exe
```

I disabled firewall and the situation didn't change. 
Any solution?

Comment: Support varies with the version of Wine and the version of adwords.  See: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=6334 You will likely get more useful information if you [edit] your question to include wine and adwords versions.

Comment: Hi,  Thanks - I sent info  but maybe someone had the same problem with another google program.

Comment: It doesn't appear that you have [edit]ed your question to include the versions I requested. As is, it's unclear (at least to me) what you are asking.

Comment: hi , I added the versions of ubuntu/adwords editor and wine .

Comment: As noted in the link I provided in my comment of 12/28/15 google adwords editor 11.x has a garbage rating under wine 1.8 All I could suggest is to try it under wine 1.75 or perhaps the development version 1.9 will provide results.

Answer (score 1):

**ETA:** The download link for the MSI is now located at https://dl.google.com/dl/adwords_editor/google_adwords_editor.msi . If this link also stops working, you can contact Google Ads support directly and ask for them to send the most recent version file to you.

---

I've found you can get AdWords Editor to install if you work from the **.msi file** rather than the EditorSetup.exe file. [The instructions here](http://adsppcmanagement.com/adwords-editor-on-ubuntu/) generally work; you might have to fiddle with your Wine settings a bit and make sure you get the right .msi version.

Remember that Google uses 4 digits in the version number for the .msi download. AdWords Editor 11.7 is at `dl.google.com/adwords_editor/`**`11.7.0.0`**`/google_adwords_editor.msi` , for example.

Comment: Google's official website unfortunately doesn't show the latest version number. You can try this search to get it: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site%3Adownloadercnet.com%20google%20adwords%20latest

Comment: This link shows the latest version numbers: https://support.google.com/adwords/editor/answer/6080641?hl=en but the MSI download link no longer works regardless.

Comment: You're right - dl.google.com/adwords_editor/12.6.0.0/google_adwords_editor.msi is now 404 :(